# Drop last character except if preceded by specific characters

Tags: r, regex

Been using R for a while but my regex skills are novice grade. I'm attempting to remove the "s" if its the final character in a word EXCEPT if its preceded by an "i" or an "s" for example. Sample...

```
dfx <- c("class","guests","trips","sassy","basis","fruits")
dfx <- sub("s$","",dfx)
View(dfx)
```

Any examples or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use lookarounds for this. I'm  not the best at them, but check out [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) tutorial to learn more.  For example  `(?<!s)s` will match an "s" that is not preceded by an "s".  Note you have to set `perl=T` for these to work in R.

```
sub("(?<!s|i)s$","",dfx,perl = T)
# [1] "class" "guest" "trip"  "sassy" "basis" "fruit"
```

Comment: that did the trick and appreciate the tutorial link. I can see many hours reviewing the material.

Answer (score 1):

`s(?<![is]s)\b` is what's needed.

https://regex101.com/r/ANyYB0/1

Benchmark showing the right way and the wrong way

```
Regex1:   s(?<![is]s)\b
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   3
Elapsed Time:    0.30 s,   295.43 ms,   295426 µs
Matches per sec:   507,741


Regex2:   (?<![is])s\b
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   3
Elapsed Time:    0.72 s,   718.22 ms,   718215 µs
Matches per sec:   208,851
```

Comment: @JeanVuda  - Screenshots of what I use http://www.regexformat.com/scrn7/s7_b1.jpg, http://www.regexformat.com/scrn7/s7_b3.jpg, http://www.regexformat.com/scrn7/s7_b2.jpg,  http://www.regexformat.com/scrn7/s7_b4.jpg

Comment: They are working! Is it VisualStudio? I guess RegexFormat is a software for this?

Comment: It's free software, runs on windows. Written with VS2015.

Comment: awesome, Thanks )